# xml element tree python add hex string to element/tag

Tags: python, xml, hex, elementtree

I can't seem to add a hex string to an element/tag in xml element tree

Here is the offending code:

```
hextext = "H:\myfilepath.myfileending"
StartTag = Element( 'StartTag' )
Data  = SubElement( StartTag, 'Data')
Data.text = str(hextext.encode(hex))
```

And I get the error

TypeError: expected a str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the string `"hex"` as parameter for `encode`, not the function `hex`:

```
Data.text = hextext.encode("hex")
```

Comment: @Ke. Please upvote the stuff that helps you. The tooltip on the upvote button literally reads "This answer is useful".